# Why does `class << self` in Ruby 'break' inheritance?

Tags: ruby

Suppose I have:

```
 class Parent
   def foo
     "foo"
   end
 end

 class Child < Parent
   class << self
 end
```

Then

```
 c = Child.new.foo
```

does not give me `"foo"`. Why not?

---

The question above came when I was messing around trying to figure out why some code with the class << self idiom was behaving in a way I didn't understand. Since I had a syntax error in this post it is obvious that the error in the code I was looking at had nothing to do with `class << self` breaking inheritance. I want to delete this Q. Stack overflow won't let me. Hope to post a better question later.

Comment: Running this from the command line results in `"t.rb:10: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end"` before it gets to `c = Child.new.foo`. If you run it in IRB (or PRY) after parsing the first three lines of `Child < Parent`, IRB says, "I'm waiting, I'm waiting", rather than `=>nil`. That should be a tip-off that something is amiss.

Comment: I'm wondering why you can't delete the question. If your edit window is open, perhaps that has to be closed first.

Comment: It says, `Sorry, this question has answers and cannot be deleted; flag it for moderator attention instead` I used to be able to delete questions I regretted posting... There must've been a meta discussion about this...

Answer (score 3):

There is a syntax error here. You never close the singleton class. Should be:

```
class Child < Parent
  class << self
  end
end
```

Works perfectly for me:

```
irb(main):008:0> class Parent
irb(main):009:1>   def foo
irb(main):010:2>     "foo"
irb(main):011:2>   end
irb(main):012:1> end
=> :foo
irb(main):013:0> class Child < Parent
irb(main):014:1>   class << self
irb(main):015:2>     def foo
irb(main):016:3>       "class-foo"
irb(main):017:3>     end
irb(main):018:2>   end
irb(main):019:1> end
=> :foo
irb(main):020:0> c = Child.new
=> #<Child:0x000001021eae30>
irb(main):021:0> c.foo
=> "foo"
irb(main):022:0> Child.foo
=> "class-foo"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 class Child < Parent
   class << self
 end
```

This definition is syntactically invalid, and doesn't make sense. The correct definition is

```
 class Child < Parent
   class << self
   end
 end
```

But even in this case, it's completely useless unless you need to define something inside the singleton class. The following code is more than enough.

```
class Parent
   def foo
     "foo"
   end
end

class Child < Parent
end
```

Here's an example

```
2.1.1 :010 > Child.new.foo
 => "foo"
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing an "end".  class << self is not a one-liner, and requires you to close the block. I just ran your code with an extra `end` and it worked.